# How to get last_comment_timestamp for a node

Tags: nodes, comments

Can someone tell me what table to look for to get the node's last_comment_timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the `node_comment_statistics` table.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $node->hasField('comment') ) { $last_comment_timestamp = $node->comment->last_comment_timestamp; }
```